# How to import several files at once according to a specific lexicographic order?

Tags: import, files-and-directories, sorting

I tried with `FileNames` but it did not give me what im looking for. My files names are

```
{ags1, ags2, ..., ags10, ags11, ..., bc1, bc2, ..., bc10, bc11, ... }
```

I needed them in that order.

Comment: @yode I believe `AlphabeticSort` is not what he wants as it puts `ags2` *after* `ags11`...

Comment: @halirutan fixed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can achieve what you want by first sorting by the name part and then turning the number part into an integer and sort it for size:

```
files = {"ags1", "ags2", "ags10", "ags11", "bc1", "bc2", "bc10", "bc11"};
SortBy[files, {
  StringTrim[#, NumberString] &, 
  ToExpression@StringTrim[#, LetterCharacter ..] &
  }
]
```

which gives your original ordering even when you randomize the entries.

Comment: ``Internal`StringToDouble`` can save some code.